# Android: CollapsingToolbarLayout with ImageView Toolbar background

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to implement a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like this:

[image]

The challenge here is that I need to have a custom `Toolbar` with a gif as background and therefore I need an `ImageView` as background for the `Toolbar`. You can see my implementation in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <!-- Container which should be scrolled parallax and contains the image gallery -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_layer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_indicators"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/defaultPadding"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Container which contains the background for the toolbar and the toolbar itself  -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <de.views.CustomTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    tools:text="Restauranttitel"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Tablayout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/selected_tab_background"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabMaxWidth="2000dp"/> <!-- we need to set this value to a very big value so that a single tab gets displayed over the full width too -->

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

With this implementation the whole view is scrolling and neither the `Toolbar` nor the `TabLayout` gets pinned to the top of the screen.

I've worked through lots of tutorials and stackoverflow answers, f.e.

- https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/
- http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

They all gave nice explanations on how to work with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I think the problem of my implementation is the `RelativeLayout` containing the `ImageView` and the `Toolbar`. When removing the `RelativeLayout` and the `ImageView` and set the collapseMode of `Toolbar` to 'pin' everything worked as expected and both the `Toolbar` and `Tablayout` gets pinned at the top of the screen if the user is scrolling. But unfortunately I need to have the `ImageView` above the `toolbar` to be able to load a GIF as `Toolbar` background.

Maybe one of you got an awesome idea on how to solve this issue. Or you've another idea how I can achieve the desired behaviour? Please let me know :)

Update: I've created an example project (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1aHkcAaWIA-dHBTZnUyeUt3eTQ) with which you can reproduce the wrong scroll behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**#.** Here I used `CollapsingToolbarLayout` height as `300dp` which is the sum of  `Toolbar`, `ImageSlider` and `TabLayout` height. Used `app:titleEnabled="false"` to hide CollapsingToolbar `title`.

**#.** Inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, added `RelativeLayout` as a container of `ViewPager`(images) and `LinearLayout`(indicator). Added attribute `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to place it below `ToolBar` and 
added `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` to show `parallax` effect during scroll.

**#.** Below `RelativeLayout`, added an `ImageView` to show `GIF` image on it. Added attribute `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` to make its height as `Toolbar` height. Added attribute `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to keep the `ImageView` fixed at `top` and `visible` before or after scroll.

**#.** Added `Toolbar` below `ImageView` to show `Toolbar` over `ImageView`. As I did not set any `background` color to `Toolbar`, it will work as `transparent`. Like `ImageView`, added `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to `Toolbar` to `pin` it always at `top`. Added attribute `android:layout_height="104dp"`, to show `Tablayout` below `Toolbar` during `collapsed` state. Here `104dp` is `Toolbar` height(`56dp` ) + `Tablayout` height(`48dp`).

**#.** Finally added `TabLayout` below `Toolbar` and added attribute `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to show it at the bottom of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

**Here is the simplified working XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <!-- Image slider container -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_layer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <!-- ViewPager -->
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <!-- Pager Indicator Container -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_indicators"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/black"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Toolbar background  :: GIF -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>

            <!-- Toolbar -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:text="Restaurant Title"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <!-- TabLayout -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabBackground="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabMaxWidth="2000dp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Container for TAB'S Fragments -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI,** as you are using custom `Toolbar` with `TextView`, you have to hide default `title` of `ActionBar`. To do this use below codes in your `Activity`:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Most welcome dear. I am really happy to solve your problem. Happy coding :)

Comment: I'm trying to make this code work, but where do I have to put in the code the ImageView (located above the three tabs)? Also, is it possibile to resize the photo to half of it's height on scroll, instead disappearing? I opened a question here (I want to achieve it exactly like in this question (with three tabs): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099251/resize-the-image-to-half-on-scrolling-down

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same except that I don't have `TabLayout` in my `Activity`. Below is how I did it, hope it helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ActivityMemoryDetail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageIndicatorLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nstScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTagsH"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Tags"/>
                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/tempView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#6d6d6d"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTagsH"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTags"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tempView1"
                        android:text="lorem, ispum, dolor, sit"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDateH"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Date"/>
                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/tempView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#6d6d6d"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDateH"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tempView2"
                        android:text="Saturday April 30, 2016 at 8:30 PM"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
        android:onClick="editMemory"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `activity_main.xml`.
Here is the code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_layer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_indicators"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/indicator"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/indicator"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/indicator"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>




            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@drawable/banner_gif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >

                <de.scrollbehaviour.CustomTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    tools:text="Titel"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


         <!-- we need to set this value to a very big value so that a single tab gets displayed over the full width too -->

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="#000000"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="2000dp"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: gif of the correct scrolling screen as needed]